# jQuery Fading/Invisibility

Tags: jquery

How can I make a `<h3>` fade out or just hide itself on my page after a few seconds once the page has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) call, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("h3").delay(3000).fadeOut();
});
```

On `document.ready` this selects all `<h3>` elements and adds a 3 second delay before their [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), just adjust the selector as needed, for example: `h3.message` for a
`<h3 class="message">`.

Here's the more general non-[`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) version of delaying any action:

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() { $("h3").fadeOut(); }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different Timer Plugins for jQuery. Here is a short example. 
[Here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers)

Its possible to set a timer and if the time is over you hide or fadeout.

Comment: There's no need for plugins here, always look at what the core library has to offer first: http://api.jquery.com/ For that matter, look at what's in vanilla JavaScript before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){$("whateverselector").fadeOut()});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){    $("#h3").fadeOut();    }, 3000);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with setTimeout function: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

```
var timeout = 3; // 3 seconds
$(function(){ // DOM ready
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("h3").fadeOut();
  }, timeout*1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(function(){
setTimeout("$('h3.classname').fadeOut()", 2000);
});
```

This will make the h3 with class classname fade out 2 seconds after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Never pass a string to `setTimeout()` if it can be avoided, use an anonymous function.